# Calculate variance of wikiPageLength with SPARQL on dbpedia

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia

I wanted to calculate variance (or standard deviation) of wikipedia page length history, for light novel books (Light_novels), with dbpedia (http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql).

The SPARQL is here:

```
PREFIX dbpedia0: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX term: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?item ((SUM((?n - ?mean)*(?n - ?mean)))/(COUNT(?n) - 1) AS ?variance) 
WHERE
{
    
?item term:subject dbc:Light_novels . 

  ?item dbpedia0:wikiPageLength ?n
  {
      SELECT ?item (AVG(?n) AS ?mean) WHERE {
        ?item dbpedia0:wikiPageLength ?n . 
      } 
  }

}
```

This gives an error `Virtuoso 37000 Error SP031: SPARQL compiler: The name ?n is used in multiple clauses, without any logical connection`
and I tried modifying the code blindlessly countless times, but ended up no idea how can I achieve that.

I really appreciate your helpful comments. Thanks.

Comment: works for me on http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Comment: you could disable the flags "Strict checking of void variables" and "Strict checking of variable names used in multiple clauses but not logically connected to each other" on http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql - I mean, it's literally what your error says.

Comment: I'd also put `?item term:subject dbc:Light_novels .` into the subquery for efficiency reasons. So you will end up with having `?item term:subject dbc:Light_novels .`  in the inner and outer query

Comment: Thanks @UninformedUser looks the error issue is solved with that. but still I get no result by the query. do you have an idea?

Comment: which endpoint do you use now? In http://dbpedia.org/sparql data for `dbo:wikiPageLength` does not exist. In  http://live.dbpedia.org/sparql it does

Comment: @UninformedUser I tried the query on the both live and general one. but no result I get in the both one. do you get result?

Comment: no, but you should get an error on live.dbpedia don't you? At least I'm getting "Virtuoso 42000 Error SR673: Invalid IRI_ID #i-8286622627166945280"

Comment: @UninformedUser I just re-tried the query on live one and got error `Virtuoso 22003 Error SR087: Non numeric argument(s) to arithmetic operation '*'`, yes.

Comment: I noticed this was not int so maybe this error right? I just changed wikiPageLength 
 to PageRevisionID and tried, but I got no result.

Comment: what was not int?

Comment: wikiPageLength is not numeric so I got the error, right?

Comment: it is numeric, try your subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally this should work

```
PREFIX dbpedia0: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX term: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>


SELECT ?item IF(?count=1,0,(SUM(?x)/(?count-1))) as ?var
{
SELECT ?item ?n xsd:integer(?n) as ?ni ?mean xsd:integer(?ni-?mean) as ?nmean ((?nmean)*(?nmean)) as ?x ?count
{
  ?item dbpedia0:wikiPageLength ?n 
  {
     SELECT ?item AVG(?n2) as ?mean (COUNT(?item)) as $count
     {
       ?item term:subject dbc:Light_novels . 
       ?item dbpedia0:wikiPageLength ?n2
     }
     GROUP BY ?item
  }
}
} GROUP BY ?item ?count
```

but it throws this error

> Internal Optimized compiler error : Bad dfe in sqlo_place_exp in sqldf.c:2491

So I have modified it to this one:

```
PREFIX dbpedia0: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX term: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT ?item IF(?count=1,-1,(?sx/(?count-1))) as ?var
{
SELECT ?item SUM(?x) as ?sx ?count
{
SELECT ?item ?n xsd:integer(?n) as ?ni ?mean xsd:integer(?ni-?mean) as ?nmean ((?nmean)*(?nmean)) as ?x ?count
{
  ?item dbpedia0:wikiPageLength ?n 
  {
     SELECT ?item AVG(?n2) as ?mean (COUNT(?item)) as $count
     {
       ?item term:subject dbc:Light_novels . 
       ?item dbpedia0:wikiPageLength ?n2
     }
     GROUP BY ?item
  }
}
} GROUP BY ?item ?count
}
```

- we need to aggregations a. for calculating the mean and b. to calculate the sum of differences of each `n` from mean.
- I needed to convert type to integer the variable `xsd:integer(?ni-?mean)`, otherwise it does not show the result of multiply
- With running the second inner subquery you can see how the variables are modified

Comment: worked! huge help, thanks. I'm working on calculate variance of wikiPageModified date data now, I appreciate that if you have an idea about this also. thanks again.